# Heroku app deployed but doesn't work, and I get an error

Tags: heroku

I feel like I am pulling my hair out, can anyone help?

It says it's deployed but when I go to the app I get an error

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       USE_YARN_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       engines.yarn (package.json):  1.21.1
       
       Resolving node version 14.x...
       Downloading and installing node 14.15.5...
       Using default npm version: 6.14.11
       Resolving yarn version 1.21.1...
       Downloading and installing yarn (1.21.1)
       Installed yarn 1.21.1
       
-----> Restoring cache
       Caching has been disabled because NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false
       
-----> Prebuild
       Running heroku-prebuild (yarn)
       yarn run v1.21.1
       $ echo This runs before Heroku installs dependencies.
       This runs before Heroku installs dependencies.
       Done in 0.06s.
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules (yarn.lock)
       yarn install v1.21.1
       [1/4] Resolving packages...
       [2/4] Fetching packages...
       info fsevents@2.3.1: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
       info "fsevents@2.3.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
       [3/4] Linking dependencies...
       [4/4] Building fresh packages...
       Done in 19.16s.
       
-----> Build
       Running heroku-postbuild (yarn)
       yarn run v1.21.1
       $ cd app && yarn && yarn build
       info No lockfile found.
       [1/4] Resolving packages...
warning react-scripts > babel-eslint@10.1.0: babel-eslint is now @babel/eslint-parser. This package will no longer receive updates.
warning react-scripts > webpack-dev-server > chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
warning react-scripts > webpack-dev-server > chokidar > fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
warning react-scripts > resolve-url-loader > rework > css > urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
warning react-scripts > resolve-url-loader > rework > css > source-map-resolve > urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
warning react-scripts > resolve-url-loader > rework > css > source-map-resolve > resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
warning react-scripts > webpack > watchpack > watchpack-chokidar2 > chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'
warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > rollup-plugin-babel@4.4.0: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-babel.
warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > @hapi/joi > @hapi/address@2.1.4: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > @hapi/joi > @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > @hapi/joi > @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > @hapi/joi > @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > @hapi/joi > @hapi/topo > @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > strip-comments > babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread > babel-runtime > core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
warning react-scripts > jest > @jest/core > jest-config > jest-environment-jsdom > jsdom > request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
warning react-scripts > jest > @jest/core > jest-config > jest-environment-jsdom > jsdom > request-promise-native@1.0.9: request-promise-native has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
warning react-scripts > jest > @jest/core > jest-config > jest-environment-jsdom > jsdom > request > har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
       [2/4] Fetching packages...
warning sha.js@2.4.11: Invalid bin entry for "sha.js" (in "sha.js").
       info fsevents@2.3.2: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
       info "fsevents@2.3.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
       info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
       info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
       [3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning " > @testing-library/user-event@12.7.0" has unmet peer dependency "@testing-library/dom@>=7.21.4".
warning "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.20.0" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
       [4/4] Building fresh packages...
       success Saved lockfile.
       $ react-scripts build
       Creating an optimized production build...
       Compiled successfully.
       
       File sizes after gzip:
       
         60.38 KB (+2 B)  build/static/js/2.e367a61a.chunk.js
         1.59 KB          build/static/js/3.6e81f958.chunk.js
         1.4 KB (+34 B)   build/static/js/main.639f44f9.chunk.js
         1.16 KB (+1 B)   build/static/js/runtime-main.ee6779e3.js
         777 B (+17 B)    build/static/css/main.bc02d1f6.chunk.css
       
       The project was built assuming it is hosted at /.
       You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.
       
       The build folder is ready to be deployed.
       You may serve it with a static server:
       
         yarn global add serve
         serve -s build
       
       Find out more about deployment here:
       
         https://cra.link/deployment
       
       Done in 91.72s.
       
-----> Pruning devDependencies
       yarn install v1.21.1
       [1/4] Resolving packages...
       [2/4] Fetching packages...
       info fsevents@2.3.1: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
       info "fsevents@2.3.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
       [3/4] Linking dependencies...
       [4/4] Building fresh packages...
       warning Ignored scripts due to flag.
       Done in 2.90s.
       
-----> Cleanup
       Running heroku-cleanup (yarn)
       yarn run v1.21.1
       $ echo This runs after Heroku prunes and caches dependencies.
       This runs after Heroku prunes and caches dependencies.
       Done in 0.09s.
       
-----> Build succeeded!
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 81.3M
-----> Launching...
       Released v65
       https://yana-scheduler.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

So https://yana-scheduler.herokuapp.com/ is deployed but when I visit the URL I get an error.

I have a Procfile file, I also have a React font-end and an Express build (hooked up to MongoDV)

Comment: I see that your app is working and all the slots are booked too

Comment: Yes, I got it woking in the end. Thank you